# Which embassy will most likely provide a multiple entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, belgium, multiple-entry

I have already travelled to schengen area once on a single entry Schengen visa. I am now trying to apply for a schengen visa with the intention of making several short trips to the schengen area.

My plan is to go to France, Belgium, the Netherlands, Germany, Spain and Portugal in the next 6 months.

Which of the above embassies is most likely to provide a multiple entry visa? I can then tailor my plans and apply to that embassy to ensure I get a multiple-entry visa.

Comment: Out of multiple first hand experiences, I suggest going to the Greek embassy. I know it is not among the choices above but they do not ask for an itinerary in advance (at least where I live) and they always issue a multiple entry visa.

Comment: Goto France and have a good deposit in your bank account. One of my friends had around £8k in his bank account and France issued him a year long Schengen visa, with multiple entries.

Comment: The accepted answer below is out of  date.  It is unwise to treat it as correct.

Comment: Italy is the easiest. Germans are the strictest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

May be you will be interested in this data. It's old by still shows dynamic how easy is getting visa C in the Schengen countries. Portugal and Netherlands looks like the best choises. 
[image]

[image]

Data from here: http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/overview_of_schengen_visa_statistics_en.pdf

[Here](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/pdf/synthese_2010_with_filters_en.xls) is also file with statistic of 2010. You may see data of issued visas by you nationality. Make your own research to choose right country.

Comment: I've compiled the [following statistics](http://i.imgur.com/CJe1j0x.png) by multiplying the multiple entry visa rate by the non-refusal rate to get the list of "optimal" Schengen embassies. It looks like Slovenia is your best bet.

Comment: +1 for fascinating raw data, but the averages should be taken with a grain of salt.  For example, Belgium's high rejection rate is almost entirely explained by the fact that its two busy embassies in its former colonies the Congos reject almost 50% of visa applications, whereas eg. the consulate in Mumbai only rejects 2%.

Comment: +1 for going beyond anecdotes. Still, interpretation is obviously contingent upon the refusal rate and on the type of application they get. Given their policy in other related areas (asylum, visas for family members, etc.) and their generally fastidious bureaucracy, I find it difficult to believe that the Netherlands is really a good place to apply. The last link might be particularly useful to try to sort this out.

Comment: NOTE: this answer is out-of-date. It should be updated to assure that the site provides current information.

Comment: @GayotFow what's the up-to-date answer?

Comment: @JonathanReez, are you adding a new answer? this one is 3 years out-of-date but has been accepted already and more up-to-date info is being blocked.

Comment: @GayotFow please add your own answer and we'll upvote it to the top :)

Comment: @lambshaanxy this makes me wonder how representation agreements are handled in the statistics.  For example, the Belgian consulates in the DRC handle applications on Germany's behalf from applicants who wish to travel to Germany.  Are these applications counted under Germany or Belgium?

Answer (score 5):

The current answers are outdated, so I took [the latest Schengen visa statistics](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy_en#paragraph_1903) and compiled the following chart for the last 3 years:

| Schengen State | In 2021 | In 2020 | In 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Slovenia | 97.07% | 66.94% | 78.36% |
| Germany | 94.50% | 90.38% | 86.85% |
| Estonia | 94.39% | 94.37% | 92.04% |
| Austria | 92.79% | 61.20% | 49.28% |
| Latvia | 89.77% | 82.63% | 78.98% |
| Greece | 89.02% | 81.46% | 76.57% |
| Luxembourg | 88.06% | 84.95% | 85.49% |
| Italy | 87.27% | 76.50% | 73.57% |
| Lithuania | 85.98% | 89.65% | 86.93% |
| Finland | 83.81% | 90.22% | 90.25% |
| Switzerland | 81.84% | 72.24% | 65.40% |
| Poland | 81.28% | 84.95% | 76.45% |
| Netherlands | 73.62% | 65.32% | 85.82% |
| Portugal | 72.83% | 52.25% | 51.62% |
| Belgium | 68.89% | 58.61% | 50.89% |
| Slovakia | 68.32% | 71.91% | 60.64% |
| Malta | 62.78% | 44.56% | 42.20% |
| Czech Republic | 60.94% | 39.59% | 25.67% |
| Spain | 59.00% | 40.83% | 44.36% |
| Norway | 57.51% | 48.67% | 26.05% |
| Denmark | 54.82% | 54.98% | 48.35% |
| France | 53.34% | 33.43% | 29.78% |
| Sweden | 50.42% | 44.81% | 26.89% |
| Hungary | 46.26% | 57.46% | 45.48% |
| Iceland | 18.19% | 13.45% | 8.80% |
| Median | 73.62% | 65.32% | 60.64% |

As we can see, median values seem to be improving year-over-year, but unfortunately multi-entry visas are still not the default. Note that these are aggregate statistics for every consulate in the world. When applying in a specific country you want to download the latest Schengen statistics file and find the consulate with the largest percentage of multi-entry visas. I.e. for India the top consulates are as follows (I've filtered the data to consulates that issued at least 100 visas):

| Country | Share of multi-entry visas in India |
| --- | --- |
| Germany | 95.34% |
| Greece | 91.02% |
| Switzerland | 90.90% |
| Lithuania | 87.25% |
| Austria | 87.08% |
| Belgium | 85.13% |
| Italy | 84.77% |
| Denmark | 78.51% |
| Luxembourg | 74.62% |
| Netherlands | 61.72% |
| Portugal | 59.55% |
| Czech Republic | 49.09% |
| Hungary | 48.72% |
| Estonia | 48.13% |
| Slovakia | 43.40% |
| Finland | 36.23% |
| France | 27.87% |
| Poland | 26.31% |
| Sweden | 22.14% |
| Iceland | 18.84% |
| Spain | 14.19% |
| Norway | 8.07% |

So if I were applying for a Schengen visa in India, I'd definitely aim for Germany rather than France. Though of course another caveat is that [we don't know](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120882/can-i-find-out-the-average-duration-of-schengen-visas-issued-by-a-particular-con?noredirect=1&lq=1) if Germany is actually issuing 6+ months Schengen visas or just allows multiple entries on visas of short duration.

Comment: That's a wrong answer. The 1st place on the list is Finland, but Finland complies to Schengen rules and always issues single-entry visas to travellers without a specific right to claim multiple-entry visas, *except* in their consulates in the North-Western Federal District of Russia, where they issue 'shopping' MEVs without even requiring any supporting documentation. As a consequence, the SPb consulate issues at least twice as much Schengen visas than any other Schengen country's consular post in the world.

Comment: @ach that is true, but I certainly wouldn't apply for a French visa if I was hoping to get a multi-entry one for example

Comment: Actually, France and Spain are widely believed to be the most probable places to get 'really ME' visas in Moscow consular areas.

Comment: How are visa applications submitted under representation agreements handled in these statistics?  For example, a resident of Algeria who needs a visa to visit Iceland must apply through the Norwegian embassy to Algeria.  Is that application counted under "Iceland" or "Norway" in these statistics?

Comment: @phoog it will count as Norway. In the explanatory notes they mention: *Liechtenstein is a Schengen associated country but does not process
short stay visa applications but is represented by Switzerland for this purpose*. I presume that the same logic applies to all other third-country representations.

Comment: I wouldn't bank on it.  The relationship between Switzerland and Liechtenstein is very much unlike the relationship between Iceland and Norway; that Liechtenstein is "Schengen associated" rather than a Schengen member state is only one difference.