# South African on a charity visa in the UK. I need a Schengen visa. What would be the easiest to get the visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens, embassies

South African on a charity visa in the UK. I need a Schengen visa. What would be the easiest to get the visa?
Where would be the easiest embassy to apply?
What documents are needed?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/which-embassy-will-most-likely-provide-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26459/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-in-another-country-than-my-main-destination

Comment: The most favourable and lenient country, only if provided with the right evidence, is France. They process fast(most of them process in 3 days) and give long duration visas. Stay away from Nordic countries, Netherlands, Switzerland as they are very stingy and mainly give single entry visas. And another reason is TLS(for France) are way much better than VFS(for other countries) in terms of service.

Comment: What kind of Schengen visa do you need? Will you be going as a tourist? To work for the charity? To study?  Something else?

Answer (score 6):

You don't get a choice of which Schengen country to apply to a visa from -- it has to be the main destination of the trip you need the visa *for*. This can be checked because you'll need to describe your travel plans and purpose in the visa application itself, and it will be rejected unless filed with the country that's your main destination.

Of course you can go to any Schengen country's consulate and claim that you want to go on a tourist/leisure trip there, without any specific plans. However, (1) that would be lying if you in fact do have particular plans, and lying on visa applications has unpleasant ways of coming back to bite people later, (2) if you're worried about being refused the visa, your best bet will be to apply to the country where you have a detailed and convincing story to tell *anyway*.

Comment: (+1) Although the OP could also be flexible and ready to adjust his or her travel plans to make things easier. Whether some consulates are easier to deal with than other is a valid question.