# How can I get Schengen visa that will be valid for at least 60 days?

Tags: multiple-entry, schengen-visas, turkish-citizens

For the last couple of years (after Arab Spring and IS), getting s Schengen visa got much harder for those who are Turkish. Last year, I applied for a tourist visa for Germany and was shocked when I got only a single entry, valid for 7 days but with a 3-days maximum visit. The scrutiny at the airport with that visa was excruciating, to say the least.

Now I would like a multiple-entry visa with a validity of 60-90 days, so that I can go to open air festivals in the summer.

I can't make a clear case to the Consulate because all tourist applications go through an intermediate agency, iData. You send the required standard documents, but it discards anything  else you submit. You can't even submit multiple round-trip flight reservations that are one month apart as documentation (e.g., 1st to 10th June AND 15th to 20th July).

How can I overcome these obstacles?

Comment: @JonathanReez dont the Schengen rules frown on visa shopping?

Comment: @Moo sure, but you can always change your plans to go to Slovenian open air festivals instead ;)

Comment: If it was your first time applying for a visa, then it is normal to be granted a limited / restricted visa. It happened to me as well when I applied for the Netherlands for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've previously had a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25705/which-embassy-will-most-likely-provide-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa) on which countries are the most likely to issue a multi-entry Schengen visa. Taking those statistics and multiplying them by each country's visa rejection rate, we arrive at a handy table listing the odds of getting a multi-entry Schengen visa from each consulate:

[image]

Finland's statistics are a bit skewed due to the large number of Russian tourists who have a special visa agreement with Finland, so your best bet is definitely to go for **Slovenia**. Luckily for you Slovenia does have an [embassy in Turkey](http://www.mzz.gov.si/en/representations_abroad/europe/turkey/), so it should be easy to apply for their visa through their partner VFS.

Obviously this means you would have to change your itinerary and it would also be wise to fly into the Schengen area through Ljubljana a couple of times. However once you are in the Schengen area nobody will stop you from going to Germany to visit an open air festival.