# How do I ask for a long validity Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I have been issued (and visited and came back before expiry) three Schengen Visas in the last two years. I am applying again for my next trip.

1. How do I ask for a long validity visa?
2. For how long can I ask the validity to be? I'd love to get a five year visa.

My previous purpose of travel was a mix of tourism and business. My future travels will also be mix of tourism and business trips.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/177714/30703 (with the relevant legal text and a bit of relevant comment, even if the question is very different).

Answer (score 4):

You can ask for a *1 year* visa.

From https://eur-lex.europa.eu/EN/legal-content/summary/visa-code.html

> Multiple-entry visas with long validity may be issued for one, two or multiple entries. The Visa Code sets out rules on the issuing of multiple entry visas with a progressively longer length of validity:
>
> - 1 year, if the applicant has used three visas within the previous 2 years;
> - 2 years, if the applicant has already used a 1-year multiple-entry visa within the previous 2 years;
> - 5 years, if the applicant has already used a 2-year multiple-entry visa within the previous 3 years.

> Airport transit visas and visas limited to particular countries are not taken into account when taking decisions on the issuing of multiple-entry visas with a long validity.

AFAIK, you apply in the normal way, including a cover letter that explains why you want a long-term visa and evidence of your previous visas.

Comment: **in theory** it’s even supposed to be automatic: after 3 short visas in 2 years they should grant a 1-year visa, then 2-years, then 5. In practice it seems to vary a lot from consulate to consulate. Restating one’s past visits (especially if the visas were from different countries) and kindly requesting a longer visa, especially if one has a strong application, is probably a good idea. They can always grant a 5 year visa “early” if the application is strong enough.

Comment: > in theory it’s even supposed to be automatic: I applied for my third one now, I'll confirm this no sooner I get my passport back.

>  if one has a strong application
I do feel my application is strong enough, I have traveled 20+ countries, have some long validity visa, have enough funding to sponsor multiple trips without  defaulting, my company does have a branch I do visit and plan to visit in future. I didn't shy about it and asked consulate for 5Y this time, will update once I get my passport back.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ask for a long validity visa?

There is no specific format / form for this request. It can be added as a request in the cover letter.

Sample:

> I am anticipating frequent future travels to France to meet my French sister company for bi-yearly sync ups. I was wondering if I can I get Multi Entry Visa for the same.
>
> Looking forward for a favourable outcome.

Further, in case of `employed applicant`,

a. seeking `tourist visa`: a note for `No Objection` for future travels can be added in `Letter of Introduction`

b. seeking `business visa`: a note for `need for for future travels` can be added in `Letter of Introduction`

> For how long can I ask the validity to be?

`Article 24` of `Schengen Visa Code` with its subclauses make validity period a subjective thing. Though what is clear is that one can ask for `max validity` of `5 years` and you can increase your chances *upto a level* by adding relevant documents anticipating future frequent possibility of travelling to Schengen.

The [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) tells us, in article 24:

> 2. Provided that the applicant fulfils the entry conditions set out in point (a) and points (c) to (e) of Article 6(1) of Regulation (EU) 2016/399, multiple-entry visas with a long validity shall be issued for the following validity periods, unless the validity of the visa would exceed that of the travel document:
>
> (a) for a validity period of one year, provided that the applicant has obtained and lawfully used three visas within the previous two years;
>
> (b) for a validity period of two years, provided that the applicant has obtained and lawfully used a previous multiple-entry visa valid for one year within the previous two years;
>
> (c) for a validity period of five years, provided that the applicant has obtained and lawfully used a previous multiple-entry visa valid for two years within the previous three years.

Do note:

> Airport transit visas and visas with limited territorial validity issued in accordance with Article 25(1) shall not be taken into account for the issuing of multiple-entry visas.

Before you think this is a no brainer:

> 2a.  By way of derogation from paragraph 2, the validity period of the visa issued may be **shortened** in individual cases where there is reasonable doubt that the entry conditions will be met for the entire period.
>
> 2b.  By way of derogation from paragraph 2, consulates shall, within local Schengen cooperation, assess whether the rules on the issuing of the multiple-entry visas set out in paragraph 2 need to be **adapted** to take account of local circumstances, and of migratory and security risks, in view of the adoption of more favourable or more restrictive rules in accordance with paragraph 2d.
>
> 2c.  Without prejudice to paragraph 2, a **multiple-entry visa valid for up to five years may be issued** to applicants who prove the need or justify their intention to travel frequently or regularly, provided that they prove their integrity and reliability, in particular the lawful use of previous visas, their economic situation in the country of origin and their genuine intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa for which they have applied.

**Personal Experience:**

I know people who got MEV without meeting 3 trips in 2 years condition.

I know people who did not get MEV even after meeting 3 trips in 2 years condition.

Ref:
[Different Context but Similar Answer](https://%20travel.stackexchange.com/a/177714/30703)